# not able to make change in react choice group

Tags: reactjs, react-native, multiple-choice

HTML

```
<ChoiceGroup
   options={ [
     { key: 'Male', text: 'Male' },
     { key: 'Female', text: 'Female' }
   ]}
   required={true}
   onChange={e=>this.changeOption()}
   selectedKey={this.gender}
/>
```

JS

```
 changeOption():void{
        if(this.gender == "Male"){
            this.gender = "Female";
        }else{
            this.gender = "Male";

        }
    }
```

Hi I am new to React I wanted to have this choice group in my project. However it is rendering as expected by  i could not change the options. Any clue?

PS: I am not supposed to use state variable here

Comment: *PS: I am not supposed to use state variable here*: Why? This is exactly what state is for

Comment: @Brain The main entity used by multiple forms. So we don't want to update that. Is there any alternative

Comment: Not using state in react is like removing your eyes to see.  Where is is the non-state requirement coming from?

Comment: show us the ```ChoiceGroup``` component.